# Exporting a Table of Graphics into Individual Files

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

The command

`Table[Polt[Sin[k x],{x,1,10}],{k,1,30}]`

generates a list of graphics. I want to export each list item as an individual jpg file, named  according to the order of appearance in the list. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything, e.g. `MapIndexed`/`Do` $+$ `Export`?

Comment: Export created a jpg, containing all of the plots! I'm not familiar with MapIndexed/Do.

Comment: Please fix up this question. Your code does not generate graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many ways to do this.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Table[ Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 1, 10}], {k, 1, 3}];
Export[ToString[#] <> ".jpg", data[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[data]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can get a little fancy, and generate the names while building the table itself

```
data = Table[ {ToString[k] <> ".jpg", Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 1, 10}]}, {k,1, 3}];
Export[First[#], Last[#]] & /@ data
```

Have fun coming up with more ways.

Comment: I would use IntegerString to generate numbers with leading zeros. That will make sure the files are sorted in the correct order when you list them.